# jQuery Cycle plugin "Zoom in" instead of fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, jquery-cycle

I have a lot of divs with images (tiles) that i would like to appear one by one when the site is opened. The jQuery Cycle Plugin supports this by using:

```
$('#slideshow img:first').fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle();
});
```

This works fine, however i would like some adjustments in this animation that i can't make myself because i simply don't know enough about jQuery and JS in general. I tried ofcoarse, but every effort failed.

What i would like is:

- The images need to appear one by one. There is not "pause" option in this plugin as far as i know. Is there an option so that i can hold the animation for a few milliseconds before it starts?
- The above code fades an image in, but i would like it to zoom/fade-in. So it looks like the tiles pop-in.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

You can use the jquery delay to achieve that:

`$('#slideshow').cycle({fx:'fadeZoom'}).pause().delay(5000).resume();`

Original Answer

The plugin has all the options that you seem to be describing:

For reference here the options: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

`$('#slideshow').cycle({fx: 'fadeZoom', delay: 1000});` is what you want to call.   The fx defines the animation and the delay will delay the start of the cycle.

Here is a list of all the animations: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/browser.html

Comment: I came this far as well, but the problem is that "delay" is ignored on the first image. So the image looks like a static image from start on. I would like it to appear when the site loads.

Comment: I appreciate your help and like what you did here, but i just would like to zoom in one image. In the fiddle you sent you posted a slideshow that starts with an image. I want to start with an empty space and "zoom" that up with an image. So the tiles move into place.

Comment: For your first image Have you tried an empty .gif/spacer.gif?  You can remove it as well.   I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's a creative solution lucuma! I think that should work, so i accepted your answer. It's not the "official" route, so if anyone else has a suggestion let me know! For now i'll use this. :)